# Xcode is not building the Binary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, build-settings

Xcode is doing something bizzare which I at one point in time fixed but now for the life of me  I can't figure out what's wrong.

Xcode is building my project fine - no errors on a clean-all build.  All my product names and info.plists agree, all the settings appear to be correct.  I've only got the one build configuration (I always delete all of them except when I got to actually release something - waay to many invisible problems with these things).

Except that it is not generating binaries for my code.

Eh wot?

I have recently checked the code out on a new computer, and I checked all the paths and everything exists where it should.

any help is appreciated.  It is not throwing any errors and neither the binary for the .app nor the .plugin (project.app/Contents/MacOS/THERE IS NOTHING HERE).

Thanks!!!

-Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UGH so the answer is that one of my linked libraries was not pointing to the proper `Dynamic Library Name` for itself.

It was something like `build/Proj.build/Development/blah...`

And it needed to be `/Library/Frameworks/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)` because that's where it was installed on the other computer.

+1 Kudos to @cdespinosa for thinking it was a linking error.

Lesson learned: if you include anything you yourself make, always `otool -L` it.

-S!

Answer (score 1):

Open your Build Results window, look at the Build Log, and find the "Linking" step. Click the transcript button on the right to show the actual command line of the linker invocation.  Look carefully at what it says it's doing.  If it's not obvious what the problem is by inspection, then drag and drop the "Linking" build step into a reply message here so others can see it.

Comment: When I open the build log, there is no "Linking" step.  It skips that step for some reason.  I have created a new project as @Ciryon suggested and copied all my files and build settings over to a new directory, but it is not building at all.

Everything builds fine on my other machine and I swear all my paths run from $(SRCROOT) or $(HOME) or the like so nothing is hard-coded to my other machine's path.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.panotools.org/Build_a_MacOSX_Universal_Hugin_bundle_with_Xcode

This will help u..

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new empty project and copy the source code files from the other project. It's hard to diagnose the problem here without the build log.

Comment: I have done this... and several hours later it is still not building a binary.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 3.2.5, after building 25 times with successful Builds I started to wonder what was going on.

I had to do Build and Archive, as it turns out. After that you get a window in the Organizer which I've never seen before (Archived Applications). There I selected the App and then the Archived build and then context menu with Show in finder. There it was and it uploaded fine to iTunes.

---

Update:

From that same sceen, Archived Applications, you can Validate and Submit your App straight to the App store. no more Application Loader. Makes the process less daunting, that's for sure.