# XCode won't generate lib, framework or app bundle; partial success with xcodebuild command

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, xcodebuild

This has been driving me nuts for a couple days now. I have been poking around on Google for hours with no luck. I have glimpsed a few tantalizingly close hits here (see link at bottom), but nothing really speaks to my situation.

First, some context. I use a program called Assignment Tracker X on OS X for organizing my school assignments. It's pretty good for what it does, but a lot of features are missing, incomplete, or just plain broken. The project is abandonware, with the last update coming over two years ago. Luckily, it's GPL and I have the source. I decided I wanted to fork my own version and put in a slew of fixes and features I've been wanting, but I can't get it to build correctly through XCode.

**The Problem**

When I go to build, it cranks through everything, no problem. Files are copied, objects and compiled, and the app bundle is touched. Build succeeded with no errors. Or even warnings. But the executable itself is never linked or copied, so trying to execute it of course fails.

**Attempts at Resolution**

Importantly, it builds correctly for MacPorts. I debugged their build script and found that the secret was a commandline build:

```
xcodebuild  -alltargets -configuration Deployment build OBJROOT=build/ SYMROOT=build/ MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 ARCHS="i386" SDKROOT="" GCC_VERSION=4.2
```

This command successfully builds the project, including linking an executable and building it into a valid app bundle. The weird part is that all of those options match the project and target settings; they're not overriding or adding anything new to my version of the project as far as I can tell.

I thought part of the problem was the old version of RBSplitView it was using, so I downloaded the source for that, and when I build it does the same thing in a completely separate project: compiles all the source files, copies resources, touches bundles, and then it's done. It doesn't link anything. It doesn't even run libtool to build the library archive. I was able to get the library, framework, and IB plugin building correctly with the following similar command:

```
xcodebuild  -target '[TARGET NAME HERE]' -configuration Debug build OBJROOT=build/ SYMROOT=build/ MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 ARCHS="i386 x86_64" SDKROOT=""
```

This is encouraging, but even the commandline build won't build RBSplitView's included test app. Every which way I try it, I am cheerfully informed there were no errors, and that building has completed successfully, but of course it hasn't.

I even completely removed XCode, and reinstalled it from a fresh download. An hour and a half later, nothing's changed.

**Other Information**

My issue is a lot like the one [Stephen Furlani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006891/xcode-is-not-building-the-binary) had, but note that his solution isn't applicable; RBSplitView only depends/links with Cocoa.framework, and it rightly resolves the path to /System/Library/Frameworks, and the app target correctly references the local lib I was able to build.

In case it's relevant: OS X 10.6.7, XCode 3.2.6

What else do you need? Ask, and ye shall receive further details.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Would you be willing to upload your project somewhere? I can try to build it with Xcode 4.

Comment: Addendum: I had the same problem some months ago building CUDA code in XCode: compiles everything just fine, doesn't link anything. I worked around this by manually adding a "Run Script" build step that just linked everything. Ugly as crap, but it worked for my own purposes.

That's absolutely not a possibility this time, because I want to submit this to OSS repositories. That would look seriously kludgey in the light of day.

Comment: @Bavarious [clicky.](http://earthian.andyc.org/digital/RBSplitView12.zip) This is the exact project and settings I was able to use a bit ago to successfully build in XCode 3.1.4 on OS X 10.5.8

Comment: All the Snow Leopard targets build just fine in Xcode 4 and I don’t see anything odd. :-/